# Very slow OS responsiveness, excessive console error messages (1 per second)

Tags: mac-mini, macos

I have a Mac Mini OSX Mountain Lion (now Mavericks) with 8GB of ram. I am a software developer and don't run extremely intensive applications concurrently on the system or anything that should be TOO memory intensive...

A few weeks ago I had an issue with the App Store doing an update of XCode. It took so long to simply click a button or even open the apple menu to restart. I once waited over 45 min for the Apple menu in the top left to open in order to shut down the computer properly...

Anyways, I finally narrowed down the problem to only occurring when the App Store was open, and it was trying to install the update for XCode. I waited days to see if it would finally finish, but the bar never moved... I finally just deleted XCode off of my computer completely and re-installed. This seemed to speed up everything again, and I was back to normal.

Yesterday I encountered some similar issues with the App Store, but a simple restart helped correct the issue.

Over the past few days I have noticed a major decline in performance and responsiveness.. Again I am not doing anything that should cause these slowdowns. It also takes a seemingly long time for the computer to go from off, to logged in and functional. I checked the Activity Monitor and everything seemed to be within normal limits, no odd readings, and the vast majority of my memory was not in use.

Today I decided that I would take a deeper look into the system to try and see if I could find any reasons for the issues. I opened the Console and I have potentially found a clue. I am getting the error `mDNSResponder[42]: ERROR: send_all(34) wrote -1 of 4 errno 32 (Broken pipe)` at the rate of exactly 1 per second, every second. It never stops.

Could this be a problem? Has anyone ever seen this before? Any known resolutions?

If I can't figure out how to speed this up, I am considering a complete re-install of the OS to get a fresh start.. How would I go about doing that? I don't have an install disk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was a bad hard drive, which should've been obvious, because it was slow getting things INTO memory, but CPU and RAM were nowhere near maxed out. Thank for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> > 1. Open Terminal.app
> > 2. Type:
> >
> >    `top -o rsize`
> >        <kbd>enter</kbd>

Look for processes that are taking much more CPU percentage (100-800% CPU) than all other processes, and also look under the `RSIZE` (RAM size) tab for excessive uses of RAM. If you find a process meets one of these criteria, grab the process ID (PID) number and do the following:

> > 1. Type:
> >
> >    `q` <kbd>enter</kbd>
> > 2. Type:
> >
> > `kill PID` <kbd>enter</kbd>
> >
> > where PID is the process ID of the program

This should bring your computer back to speed. It also reveals the problematic program, as well as what the problem is (CPU usage, RAM usage, etc). This information should be able to help you work out the exact problem/solution